# Is IDF format file viewable in Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to export circuit file to idf format in Altium Designer and see it on Forge. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, as @Guillaume mentioned, the supported formats are listed in that page. It looks no IDF. Is it possible you could export IDF to some general formats that Forge can support? e.g. STL, IGES, OBJ etc..

Comment: Get it. Ill try

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the forge viewer, you will find a list of supported formats for translation here :
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

To visualiaze a file in forge viewer you need to previously upload, then translate it to SVF/SVF2 which is the viewer default format